# How to call 2 javascript function simeltaneously

Tags: javascript, php, html

I want to check emailid format as well as check weather that email id exists in the database simultaneously as soon as the user moves to next field.

MY HTML CODE:

```
<input type="email" 
       name="mail" 
       placeholder="Email Address" 
       required="required"
       onkeyup="checkuser(this.value)"
       onblur="validateEmail(this);"/>
```

MY JAVASCRIPT CODE:

```
function chckuser(val)
{
    $.ajax({
        type:"POST",
        url:"checkuser.php",
        data: 'mail='+val,
        success: function(data){
            $("#msg").html(data);
        }
    });
}


function validateEmail(emailField){
    var reg = /^([A-Za-z0-9_\-\.])+\@([A-Za-z0-9_\-\.])+\.([A-Za-z]{2,4})$/;

    if (reg.test(emailField.value) == false) 
    {
        alert('Invalid Email Address');
        return false;
    }

    return true;
}
```

Comment: Calling two functions in an inline event handler is the same as calling two functions anywhere else, i.e., just put the calls one after the other: `onblur="f1(); f2();"`, or to call the second function only if the first returns true: `onblur="if (f1()) { f2() }"`. (Not that I'm condoning inline event handlers.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should runs these 2 functions inside another function.

Example:

```js
 function handleBlur(emailField) {
  if ( ! validateEmail(emailField)) { return false; }

  chckuser(emailField.value);
}

function chckuser(val)
{
  $.ajax({
      type:"POST",
      url:"checkuser.php",
      data: 'mail='+val,
      succss: function(data){
          $("#msg").html(data);
      }
  });
}


function validateEmail(emailField){
  var reg = /^([A-Za-z0-9_\-\.])+\@([A-Za-z0-9_\-\.])+\.([A-Za-z]{2,4})$/;

  if (reg.test(emailField.value) == false) 
  {
      alert('Invalid Email Address');
      return false;
  }

  return true;
}
```

```html
<input type="email" name="mail" placeholder="Email Address" required="required" onblur="handleBlur(this);"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Since Javascript is run in one thread in the browser you cannot do two things at same time. However I would first check just the email address format, if it is valid then make call to the back-end to check if it exists.